# Apache 2.4 ReverseProxy to Internal CentOS 7 GitLab Server

Tags: apache, gitlab, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, centos7

I have been trying to setup Apache as a ReverseProxy to an internal Gitlab server with no success.

We are running multiple virtual servers, each server having a different application. We have an existing server with Apache 2.4 installed on CentOS 6.6 and working, and I just recently stood up a new server with GitLab 8.12 on CentOS 7. I have made the following change in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'http://mypublic.domain.com:80'
```

I have added the following rules in iptables

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I have verified that we can ssh in using http://mypublic.domain.com:22

I have tried every setup I could find online to set the VirtualHost in httpd.conf, but nothing is working correctly. Below are a couple of the more recent, simple examples I have found. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.000:80>
   ServerName mypublic.domain.com
   RewriteEngine On
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.999/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.999/
</VirtualHost>

####

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.000:80>
    ServerName mypublic.domain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Location />
        Require all granted
        ProxyPass http://192.168.1.999:80
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.999:80
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

####

Apache Server: 192.168.1.000
GitLab Server: 192.168.1.999
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you can use this ip 192.168.1.000 ?? Don't think 000 is meant for usage. The external URL variable is meant for direct usage I suggest you restore it to the original.  Gitlab already uses Nginx for reverse proxy by default, may not be a good idea to reverse proxy it again, try port forwarding instead.

Comment: I put .000 and .999 just as examples, those are not the actual IP addresses of our servers. I realize they are internal addresses, but I changed them for security reasons. Also, we use a standalone Apache server for all of our applications for security and training purposes. We would like to conform to our existing architecture.

Comment: Try removing the external URL variable. It's meant for accessing gitlab directly not via reverse proxy. The request from reverse proxy will be sent as IP address not hostname.  If you use that variable gitlab will configure nginx's own virtual host.

Comment: I have tried that to no avail, which VirtualHost configuration should I use, or would you suggest any changes?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in both the reverse proxy config.
first may is simpler, start with that.
You may also want to check the error logs being generated.  You can add the below line to generate error logs for vhost in separate file and check what is the actual msg. 
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/{example.tld}/error.log
or
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/{example.tld}-error.log